# How can I add a comment to user on an app that has a relationship many-to-many with another model that has a relationship with other?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, many-to-many, comments

I get a huge stuck. now I have many of models which has a relationship between them at many apps I 'll explain that as following:
- The first model is (**UserProfile**) that has (**one to one**) relation with (**User**) model
also, I have (**UserAsking**) that has relation (**ForeignKey**) with (**UserProfile**) and last part is (**Comment**) That has (**Many to many**) relations with (**UserAsking**).
 in this case, I want to make a comment and this comment that has a relationship with **UserAsking** model. I'm in trouble, how can I do that?
I find that (**many-to-many**) is different from any another relationship and I can't get the instance as an argument in (**Comment**) model
if anyone can give me any help?
thank you in advance

account/models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

CHOICE = [('male', 'male'), ('female', 'female')]


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    overview = models.TextField(editable=True, blank=True, default='You have no an Overview yet')
    city = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False)
    phone = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True)
    sex = models.CharField(max_length=10, default='male', choices=CHOICE)
    skill = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='You have no skills yet')
    logo = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', default='images/default-logo.jpg', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username


def create_profile(sender, **kwargs):
    if kwargs['created']:
        user_profile = UserProfile.objects.create(user=kwargs['instance'])


post_save.connect(receiver=create_profile, sender=User)
```

community/models.py

```
from django.db import models
from account.models import UserProfile
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

CHOICE = [('Technology', 'Technology'), ('Computer Science', 'Computer Science'),
          ('Lawyer', 'Lawyer'), ('Trading', 'Trading'),
          ('Engineering', 'Engineering'), ('Life Dialy', 'Life Dialy')
]


class UserAsking(models.Model):
    userprofile = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, help_text='Be specific and imagine you’re asking a question to another person')
    question = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=False, help_text='Include all the information someone would need to answer your question')
    field = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=CHOICE, default='Technology', help_text='Add the field to describe what your question is about')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Comment(models.Model):
    userasking = models.ManyToManyField(UserAsking)
    comment = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
```

community/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_list_or_404
from .forms import UserAskingForm, CommentForm
from .models import UserAsking
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required


@login_required
def user_asking(request):
    form = UserAskingForm
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserAskingForm(request.POST, instance=request.user.userprofile)
        if form.is_valid():
            asking = form.save(commit=False)
            asking.title = form.cleaned_data['title']
            asking.question = form.cleaned_data['question']
            asking.field = form.cleaned_data['field']
            asking = UserAsking.objects.create(userprofile=request.user.userprofile,
                                               title=asking.title,
                                               question=asking.question,
                                               field=asking.field)
            asking.save()
            return redirect('community:user_questions')
    else:
        form = UserAskingForm()
        return render(request, 'community/asking_question.html', {'form': form})

    return render(request, 'community/asking_question.html', {'form': form})


@login_required
def user_questions(request):
    all_objects = UserAsking.objects.all().order_by('-title')
    all_objects = get_list_or_404(all_objects)
    return render(request, 'community/user_questions.html', {'all_objects': all_objects})


def question_view(request, user_id):
    my_question = UserAsking.objects.get(pk=user_id)
    comment_form = CommentForm
    #x = request.user.userprofile.userasking_set
    if request.method == 'GET':
        comment_form = comment_form(request.GET)
        if comment_form.is_valid():
            comments = comment_form.save(commit=False)
            comments.comment = comment_form.cleaned_data['comment']
            # you have to edit on userasking instance
            #comments = Comment.objects.create(userasking=request.user.userprofile.userasking_set, comment=comments)
            comments.save()
            #return render(request, 'community/question_view.html', {'x': x})

    return render(request, 'community/question_view.html', {'my_question': my_question,
                                                            'comment': comment_form})
```

community/forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import UserAsking, Comment


class UserAskingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    title = forms.CharField(required=True,
                            widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Type Your Title...',
                                                          'class': 'form-control',
                                                          'data-placement': 'top',
                                                          'title': 'type your title',
                                                          'data-tooltip': 'tooltip'
                                                          }),
                            help_text='Be specific and imagine you’re asking a question to another person')
    question = forms.CharField(required=True,
                               widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'placeholder': 'Type Your Details Of Your Question...',
                                                            'class': 'form-control',
                                                            'data-placement': 'top',
                                                            'title': 'type your question simply',
                                                            'data-tooltip': 'tooltip'
                                                            }),
                               help_text='Include all the information someone would need to answer your question')

    class Meta:
        model = UserAsking
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ['userprofile']


class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    comment = forms.CharField(max_length=500, required=False, widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'placeholder': 'Type your comment simply',
                                                                                           'class': 'form-control'}))

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ['comment']
```

community/question_view.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %} This Question Belong To User: {{ request.user }} {% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <!-- Full Question View -->
    <div class="my_question">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="answer-question">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="title">
                            <h3 class="text-primary">{{ my_question.title }}</h3>
                            <span class="clock">1 hour ago</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="question">
                            <p class="">{{ my_question.question }}</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field">
                            <span>{{ my_question.field }}</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Options e.g 'Edit, Comment, Delete etc...' -->
    <div class="options">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <a data-showin=".my-form" class="showin">Comment</a>&nbsp; | &nbsp;
                <a href="">Edit</a>&nbsp; | &nbsp;
                <a href="">Delete</a>
                <span>
                    <a href="">Like</a>&nbsp; | &nbsp;
                    <a href="">Unlike</a>
                </span>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <!-- Comment Text -->
            <div class="user-answer">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        {% for field in comment %}
                        <p>(medo) - sub comment</p>
                        <p>1 hour ago</p>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Comment Field -->
            {% include 'community/comment_form.html' %}
            {{ x }}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

community/comment_form.html

```
<form method="get" action="" class="hide my-form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="row">
        {% for field in comment %}
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ field }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Add Comment</button>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</form>
```

community/urls.py

```
from . import views
from django.urls import path

app_name = 'community'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.user_questions, name='user_questions'),
    path('ask-question/', views.user_asking, name='user_asking'),
    path('ask-question/question-view/<int:user_id>/', views.question_view, name='question_view'),
]
```

Comment: I am afraid I have not fully understood your problem: Do you want to add a comment to a question (```UserAsking``` instance)?

Comment: No, UserAsking it doesn't correct to be instance for Comment that I know. I need to make instance for Comment model to be able to do comment for user